# How to get Jackson JsonProperty of enum values in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums, jackson, annotations

I'm building a schema generator and I'm trying to get the `JsonProperty` of enum values, for example, for this class:

```
enum class Size {
    @JsonProperty("really-tall") TALL,
    @JsonProperty("really-grande") GRANDE;
}
```

I'd like to get the list `"really-tall", "really-grande"`.

How do I access the annotation of an enum?
Thanks!

UPDATE:

Solution based on this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73345969/5737533) for a generic `KType`:

```
return (jvmErasure.java as Class<Enum<*>>)
  .enumConstants
  .map {
    it.javaClass.getField(it.name).getAnnotation(JsonProperty::class.java)?.value // Get the JsonProperty string first if exists
      ?: it.name
  }
```

Comment: You can take the answer from here, replacing `Temp` with `Size` and `SerialName` with `JsonProperty`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305923/how-to-access-every-serialname-associated-with-each-enum-constant-in-an-enum-cla/71308463#71308463

Comment: Here's an answer that uses Jackson to extract the text value of an enum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70676380/jackson-serialization-for-enum-without-quotes/72977520#72977520. The benefit is that it works even if no `@JsonProperty` is defined. It's in Java, but it's easy to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Additional question from OP

> How do I make the first approach work for a generic KType

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> getJsonPropertyAnnotations() = enumValues<T>().map {
    it.declaringClass
        .getField(it.name)
        .getAnnotation(JsonProperty::class.java)
        .value
}

class SomeTest : StringSpec({
    "getJsonPropertyAnnotations" {
        getJsonPropertyAnnotations<Size>() 
            shouldBe listOf("really-tall", "really-grande")
    }
})
```

Please note that with Kotlin 1.7, IntelliJ may show a deprecation warning with wrong replacement for `declaringClass` in `getJsonPropertyAnnotations`. I guess this will be sorted out in later versions. [Link to related source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/eb3bbc326563e069585eb03fdd74fc13bc36f32e/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMapping.kt#L117)

---

The following code should do what you want.

```
class SomeTest : StringSpec({
    "getting annotation values" {
        val result = enumValues<Size>().map {
            it.declaringClass.getField(it.name).getAnnotation(JsonProperty::class.java).value
        }
        result shouldBe listOf("really-tall", "really-grande")
    }
})
```

An alternative (less code): Add a String property to your enum class (I called it someFieldName in the below code), annotate with `@get:JsonValue`, and construct each enum entry with the string value you want. `@get:JsonValue` will use someFieldName instead of the enum value during serialization.

```
enum class Size(@get:JsonValue val someFieldName: String) {
    TALL("really-tall"),
    GRANDE("really-grande");
}
```

Same test again

```
class SomeTest : StringSpec({
    "getting prop values" {
        val result = enumValues<Size>().map {
            it.someFieldName
        }
        result shouldBe listOf("really-tall", "really-grande")
    }
})
```

We're using the latter approach in an ongoing project.

Comment: Thanks! How do I make the first approach work for a generic `KType`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Kotlin implementation of the technique suggested by user @aSemy.

It's an extension function on ObjectMapper for asking the mapper how it would serialize the values of an enum. This is more robust that just inspecting the `@JsonProperty` annotation, since it works with `@JsonValue` as well as any custom annotation introspectors registered with the mapper.

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> ObjectMapper.enumValues() : List<String> {
    return convertValue(
        kotlin.enumValues<T>(),
        jacksonTypeRef<List<String>>()
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
println(jsonMapper().enumValues<Size>())
```